# MySQL not returning error in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, web

Got this line in my database class,

```
$return = mysql_fetch_array($data) or 
          $this->dberror("Error fetching data<br/>" . mysql_error());
```

but all the site puts out is: Error fetching data

Comment: $data probably isn't a mysql result object.  It's hard to say anything for sure without more info.

Comment: What is the `$data` variable contain?

Comment: have you tried the die(mysql_error())

Comment: PLEASE don't use this. The manual has a big red warning on it saying "Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used."

Comment: Example. Got another function in the class called "query". ` function query($data) {
  $get = mysql_query($data) or $this->dberror("Error getting data<br/>" . mysql_error());
  return $get;
 }` On site, I'd call $get = $db->query("SELECT * ECT..."); followed by $result = $db->fetch($get);

Answer (score -2):

Try this: echo("Error: " .  mysql_error($con));

Replace $con with your connection variable.

Comment: mysql_error(), and all of the mysql functions, use the last used connection, so that should be redundant.

Comment: I dont have a connection variable. Just basic mysql_conenct($host, $username, $password); and a mysql_select_db($database);